# Php Mysqli how to sum two different condition result

Tags: php, mysqli

Below query works but it shows two different sum of different orders perfectly as i made `GROUP BY ORDER_ID` as `(1000, 2000)`.

But i want this `(1000, 2000)` as (3000). If there are 2 orders in a week 1 has percentage based discount and one is without discount and each order has different delivery charge.

**Each order has different discount percentage, and different delivery charge.**
That's why i did `group by order_id` in my query and if i removes `group by order_id` it gives me a different total amount. But With the `group by order_id` it shows the correct amount of as much orders are in the current week or month or year.

Please help in this regard.
Below is my query what im trying to do.

```
$totalX = "select sum(price) as price, coupon, city, delivery_type, order_id
from orders where date between '2018-09-12' and '2018-09-13' group by order_id";
$totalXx = $dba2->query($totalX);
while ($total = $totalXx->fetch_assoc()) {

    $couponX = "select coupon, price, percent from couponsAll where id = '".$total['coupon']."'";
    $couponXx = $dba->query($couponX);
    $coupon = $couponXx->fetch_assoc();

    $areaBX = "select * from countries_citiesALL where id = '".$total['city']."' ";
    $areaBXx = $dba->query($areaBX);
    $areaBXxx = $areaBXx->fetch_assoc();

    $area6X = "select * from delivery_typeALL where area = '".$total['city']."' and id = '".$total['delivery_type']."'";
    $area6Xx = $dba->query($area6X);
    $area6xXx = $area6Xx->fetch_assoc();
    $dchargezQ = $area6xXx['price'];

    if ($coupon['price'] >= 1 && $coupon['percent'] < 1) {
        /// this condition is if price based discount
        $priceAcoup = $total['price'] - $coupon['price'];
        $gtotalx = $priceAcoup + $areaBXxx['price'] + $dchargezQ;
        $gtotal = number_format($gtotalx, 3);
        echo '<font color="black" style=""><b>'.$gtotal.'</b></font>';
    } else {
        if ($coupon['price'] < 1 && $coupon['percent'] >= 1) {
            /// this condition is if percentage based discount
            $priceAcoup = $total['price'] - (($total['price'] * $coupon['percent']) / 100);
            $gtotalx = $priceAcoup + $areaBXxx['price'] + $dchargezQ;
            $gtotal = number_format($gtotalx, 3);
            echo '<font color="black" style=""><b>'.$gtotal.'</b></font>';
        } else {
            /// this condition is if there is no percentage or price based discount
            $gtotalx = $total['price'] + $areaBXxx['price'] + $dchargezQ;
            $gtotal = number_format($gtotalx, 3);
            echo '<font color="black" style=""><b>'.$gtotal.'</b></font>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "unable to" mean? What did you try? What goes wrong? Here's a simple solution: put `$totalPrice = 0;` outside the top of the while loop. Put `$totalPrice += $total['price'];` inside the while loop. Put `echo $totalPrice;` outside the end of the while loop. If you have two rows in your results where price is 1000 in  one row, and 2000 in the other row, then that code should echo 3000. Obviously you should amend it to output the value in the place where you actually want to show it. But basically it's just a simple case of adding the numbers together.

Comment: can you give us example table to help you.  Because the 'sum' function in mysql dont care the 'group by',  as i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well issue is resolved as mentioned below.

I changed `$weekTotal[]` under every condition with `$weekTotal1[], $weekTotal2[], $weekTotal3[]` and put this `$weekTotal1=array();, $weekTotal2=array();, $weekTotal3=array();` above the 2nd query loop and got it working.

Thanks for your kind assistance.

```
$__xz_rTorders1     = $dba2->query("SELECT count(distinct(order_id)) as count, order_id, date FROM orders_confirmed
group by WEEK(date), MONTH(date)
order by WEEK(date), MONTH(date)
");
while($__xz_rTordersa4 = $__xz_rTorders1->fetch_assoc()) {

$__xz_signupweek = $__xz_rTordersa4['date'];
/*start day*/
for($__xz_i = 0; $__xz_i <7 ; $__xz_i++) {
 $__xz_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-".$__xz_i."days", strtotime($__xz_signupweek)));
 $__xz_dayName = date('D', strtotime($__xz_date));
 if($__xz_dayName == "Sun") {
//echo "<b>From:</b> ". date( "d/m/Y", strtotime($__xz_date))." / ";
$mstart_date=date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($__xz_date));
 }
}
/*end day*/
 for($__xz_i = 0; $__xz_i <7 ; $__xz_i++) {
 $__xz_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$__xz_i."days", strtotime($__xz_signupweek)));
 $__xz_dayName = date('D', strtotime($__xz_date));
 if($__xz_dayName == "Sat") {
//echo "<b>To:</b> ". date( "d/m/Y", strtotime($__xz_date));
$mend_date=date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($__xz_date));
 }
 }

///////////////////***********///////////////////
$weekTotal1=array();
$weekTotal2=array();
$weekTotal3=array();
///////////////////***********///////////////////

$totalX= "select sum(price) as price, coupon, city, delivery_type, order_id
from orders_confirmed where date between '".$mstart_date."' and '".$mend_date."'
group by order_id
";
$totalXx= $dba2->query($totalX);
while ($total = $totalXx->fetch_assoc()){

$couponX= "select coupon, price, percent
from coupons
where id = '".$total['coupon']."'
";
$couponXx= $dba->query($couponX);
$coupon = $couponXx->fetch_assoc();

$areaBX= "select * from countries_cities
where id = '".$total['city']."' ";
$areaBXx= $dba->query($areaBX);
$areaBXxx= $areaBXx->fetch_assoc();

$area6X= "select * from delivery_type
where area = '".$total['city']."'
and id = '".$total['delivery_type']."'
";
$area6Xx= $dba->query($area6X);
$area6xXx= $area6Xx->fetch_assoc();
$dchargezQ= $area6xXx['price'];


if ($coupon['price'] >= 1 && $coupon['percent'] < 1) {
$priceAcoup1=$total['price']-$coupon['price'];
///////////////////***********///////////////////
$weekTotal1[] = $priceAcoup1+$areaBXxx['price']+$dchargezQ;
///////////////////***********///////////////////

}else if ($coupon['price'] < 1 && $coupon['percent'] >= 1) {
$priceAcoup2=$total['price']-(($total['price']*$coupon['percent'])/100);

///////////////////***********///////////////////
$weekTotal2[] = $priceAcoup2+$areaBXxx['price']+$dchargezQ;
///////////////////***********///////////////////

}else{
///////////////////***********///////////////////
$weekTotal3[] = $total['price']+$areaBXxx['price']+$dchargezQ;
///////////////////***********///////////////////

} 

} // End Of While Loop (2nd)
$weekTotal_val3 =  array_sum($weekTotal1);
$weekTotal_val4 =  array_sum($weekTotal2);
$weekTotal_val5 =  array_sum($weekTotal3);

$finalTOTAL=number_format($weekTotal_val3+$weekTotal_val4+$weekTotal_val5,3); 
echo '<font color="red" style=""><b>'.$finalTOTAL.'</b></font>';
} // End Of While Loop (1st)
```